# Word for Crowdsourcing in the reverse direction (or antonym for Crowdsourcing)

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, antonyms

Generally, [Crowdsourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing) means leveraging others' abilities and facilities to perform tasks. Simply someone assign its work to a group.
So, what's the word for the reverse operation: a group of independent persons, e.g. researchers, send their specific tasks, e.g. an experiments, to a specific person that has such a capabilities to do that.

Comment: Expertsourcing! :)

Comment: @NVZ, Interesting idea!(+1), possible candidate for acceptance. Search result for that : http://www.zdnet.com/article/crowdsourcing-try-expert-sourcing/

Comment: it's not an antonym. Reads more like a subset of crowdsourcing.

Comment: Seems to be appropriate and could be considered as a good answer, however I'm waiting for more!

Comment: Isn't that essentially what the source of crowdsourcing, viz. ***outsourcing***, means? Or at least used to mean before it started meaning “get rid of jobs in expensive countries and send it all to India where the pay and workers’ rights are lower”…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Let me explain the scenario: someone has a robot and want to provide students with a service : applying their own related algorithms on the robot and get back them the results. Is this outsourcing?

Comment: That just sounds like "providing a service" to me.  If it's the sort of service that very few other people can provide you could call it an *expert service*.

Comment: This sounds exactly like **outsourcing**. 

Companies primarily outsource to reduce certain costs — such as
peripheral or "non-core" business expenses... production
and/or labor costs
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outsourcing

Answer (score 1):

This also sounds like ***consulting***, as in a group of independent persons approach a *consultant* having the capabilities they need.

ODO:

> **[consulting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consulting)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> [mass noun] **The business of giving expert advice to other
>   professionals**.
>
> ‘preference will be given to applicants with some experience in
>   consulting for industry’
>
> ‘Manning has more than 20 years of experience in strategy and
>   operations management consulting.’
>
> ‘A qualified architect or engineer that specializes in roof consulting
>   can help you make this decision by offering professional guidance for
>   the choice.’
>
> ‘By then, he'd become a barrister, then a senior lecturer in
>   criminology at Melbourne University, and then moved into private
>   consulting.’

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several perspectives here :

1. the group of researchers
2. an individual researcher
3. the consultant/SME.

This answer is looking at #1.

*The independent researchers could be **working as a [loose] co-operative** if they are negotiating a deal with the consultant/SME which is better that they could get as individuals.*

> A cooperative (also known as co-operative, co-op or coop) is an autonomous association of people united voluntarily to meet their common economic, social and cultural needs and aspirations through a jointly owned and democratically controlled business 
>   — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative)

Answer (score 0):

If Crowdsource is the appeal to a collective to share and consolidate expenses for a want or need *to be satisfied* by me, on consignment (delayed gratification),

the reverse of this would be for me to wholly assume the expense to ***hire*** or ***contract*** an individual *to satisfy* me.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are seeking may be *subject matter expert*, often referred to as an SME.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert):

> A subject-matter expert (SME) or domain expert is a person who is an
>   authority in a particular area or topic.

In my experience, the term *subject matter expert* is used much more broadly than indicated in this reference or in other references I could find readily. As to the use of the term, I offer the following example: Let's say an individual receives a dose of ionizing radiation from exposure to radioactive material. If one wanted to quantify the dose received, one might call in a *subject matter expert* to perform a dose assessment.

From [*the balance*](https://www.thebalance.com/subject-matter-expert-2275099) (just one of many possible examples):

> A Subject Matter Expert in business (also known as a SME) is an
>   individual with a deep understanding of a particular process,
>   function, technology, machine, material or type of equipment.
>
> Individuals designated as subject matter experts are typically sought
>   out by others interested in learning more about or leveraging their
>   unique expertise to solve specific problems or help meet particular
>   technical challenges.

*Domain expert* is another possibility, but it would not be my preference.